# Fully responsiove images in 3 div's side by side

Tags: html, css

So I want these 3 div's to work side by side and the images to be responsive. when I try to set max-width or something it breaks up. Help me out on this one.

```css
.fl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  height: 35%;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.pic {
  width: 34%;
}

.caro {
  /* border: 2px solid black; */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  /* z-index: ; */
}

.caro img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  transition: all .3s;
}

.caro img:hover {
  filter: brightness(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="fl">
  <div class="pic">
    <a href="#" class="caro"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </div>

  <div class="pic">
    <a href="#" class="caro"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </div>

  <div class="pic">
    <a href="#" class="caro"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi and welcome to SO. Please take the tour first: https://stackoverflow.com/tour -> Then read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -> After that please edit the question to meet the guidelines. What have you tried so far? what does not work as inteded? What does the question have to do with visual-studio-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest two things:

1. Use calc to get a third with `calc(100% / 3)`, instead of setting the width to a total of (3*34=) 102%.
2. Use `object-fit: cover` on the images to make them fit. I used different sizes on the images, so it's obvious that they are scaling.
3. Don't use `all` for transition, because that can cause janky animations due to the browser having to loop through all animatable properties. Always specify what you animate; it's easier to understand the code as well.

Using percentage for `height` doesn't automatically take the parent's height, so I had to improvise and use `vh` (viewport height).

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.fl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 35vh;
}

.fl > .pic {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
}

.caro img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;

  filter: brightness(0.5);
  transition: filter .3s;
}

.caro img:hover {
  filter: brightness(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="fl">
  <div class="pic">
    <a href="#" class="caro"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/300"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="pic">
    <a href="#" class="caro"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50/80.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="pic">
    <a href="#" class="caro"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt=""></a>
  </div>

</div>
```